# is it possible to catch 404 error without exit run in python?

Tags: url, python-3.x, download, http-status-code-404

I want to download a bunch of url list by:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

but sadly, few links are broken. and when urlretrieve meets that broken link

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Users/hyungsoo/PycharmProjects/untitled/check.py", line 71, in <module>
....blah_blah....
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

give me this error sign and program exited.

how to pass the broken url?

and moreover, is it possible to program tells me what link is broken?

Comment: Can you post your networking code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a "try...except..." statement, which you may find helpful. The "try" portion will attempt the given code, but the 
"except" portion will be ready for the error message. It is really a wonderful feature. See teh following example:

```
while True:
...     try:
...         x = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
...         break
...     except ValueError:
...         print "Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again..."
```

Note: Code taken from [python APIs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).